# How to include and install debian/package.timer file inside deblan package, alongside the package.service

Tags: debian-installer, systemd-timer

I'm creating a debian package which comprises of a service and some shell scripts and would like to also install a timer in the /lib/systemd/system folder so that the service will get called periodically.

According to the debian helper guide
https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_enable.1.en.html
this can be achieved by simply creating a package.timer file along with the package.service file in the debian folder and it will automatically get included in the package when building (sudo debuild -us -uc -d).

When I build, only the service is included and installed, not the timer file. For info, I can add a package.socket file and this gets included but not timer or tmpfile . I hope someone can help me.

For illustration, some of my package files are as follows.

hello-world.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello world service.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo HELLO WORLD!

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

hello-world.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for periodic execution of hello-world service.

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5s
OnBootSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

control file

```
Source: hello-world
Maintainer: Joe Bloggs <joe.bloggs@jondoe.com>
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 1.0.0
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), dh-systemd (>= 1.5)

Package: hello-world
Architecture: amd64
Depends:
Description:
 Hello world test app.
```

rules file

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@  --with=systemd

override_dh_auto_build:
    echo "Not Running dh_auto_build"

override_dh_auto_install:
    echo "Not Running dh_auto_install"

override_dh_shlibdeps:
    echo "Not Running dh_shlibdeps"

override_dh_usrlocal:
    echo "Not Running dh_usrlocal"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For automatic timer support, you need [`dh_installsystemd`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html), which is available in debhelper compatibility levels 11 and up. You should use level 12 or above. Specify this in your `control` file:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 12)
```

Delete the `compat` file, and change your `rules` to omit the explicit `systemd` sequence:

```
%:
    dh $@
```

Debhelper compatibility level 12 is available in Debian 10 and later, and in Debian 9 through backports. If you need to use an older level, you’ll have to install the support files manually, as done for example [in `anacron`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/anacron/-/blob/master/debian/rules):

```make
override_dh_auto_install:
    ...
    install -D -m 644 debian/anacron.timer debian/anacron/lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm running ubuntu 16.4, which is Debian 9. Can you tell me how to backport to use level 12 please?

Comment: Ah, debhelper 12 isn’t available for Ubuntu 16.04; you should use the approach I describe at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, if you need to install 2 services along this timer, you need/can to override it in `override_dh_installinit`:

```
override_dh_installinit:
   dh_installinit --name=anacron
   dh_installinit --name=anacron-service2
   install -D -m 644 debian/anacron.timer > debian/anacron/lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer
```